# Create virtual machine from win10 installation

Tags: windows-10

I've bought a new laptop, which came with win10 installed. I don't need that – I'm wiping it clean and installing linux. however I was wondering: maybe I can – sorry if my wording is a little off here – somehow create an "image" from my win10 installation, and then use it as a virtual machine? I think I've once read something to this effect, but I'm not sure.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible and the process is called "Physical to Virtual" or P2V. There are a variety of utilities to do this, though most of your selection will be based on the HyperVisor you're going to use eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Disk2vhd is a utility that creates VHD versions of physical disks for use in Microsoft Virtual PC or Microsoft Hyper-V virtual machines (VMs). The difference between Disk2vhd and other physical-to-virtual tools is that you can run Disk2vhd on a system that’s online. Disk2vhd uses Windows' Volume Snapshot capability to create consistent point-in-time snapshots of the volumes you want to include in a conversion. You can even have Disk2vhd create the VHDs on local volumes, even ones being converted (though performance is better when the VHD is on a disk different than ones being converted).

Comment: This answer would be improved by including the steps necessary to use Disk2VHD. Right now you're just recommending software. With a bit more information it could become a very good answer.